# How to navigate to next git modification in file?

Tags: phpstorm

If one file have multiple changes, how to navigate between them (shortcut keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up/Down or Navigate | Previous Change/Next Change.

Comment: shortcut not working but might be something with Ubuntu.

Comment: This could also be some default Ubuntu shortcut - you can always remap it via File | Settings | Keymap or use it from Navigate menu or from Ctrl+Shift+A.